# How do I access my mirror hard drive in Windows Vista?

Tags: hard-drive, mirroring

I have Windows Vista and I need to access my mirror hard drive. Could someone please tell me on how to do that? I need to delete some data from my mirror hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is your drive mirrored?

If this is a Raid mirrored drive, then it is an exact copy of your working drive, so to delete some on the mirrored drive, you just delete it on the working drive.

If it is not Raid, then you need to provide more information on how it works.